# Qt installer framework fails

Tags: javascript, c++, qt, installation

I have troubles with displaying all processes that use certain dll on Introduction page of installer. I have tried the following code:

```
Controller.prototype.IntroductionPageCallback = function()
    {
        var page = gui.currentPageWidget();
        if (page != null)
        {
            page.title = "<p style='font-size: 14px;" +
                                   "font-weight: normal;" +
                                   "font-style: italic;" +
                                    ("") +
                                   "font-variant: small-caps;'>" + copyright + " </p>";

            if (installer.isInstaller())
            {
                var msg = "";

                var ar = installer.execute("cmd", ['/C', 'tasklist', '/M']);
                msg += ar[0]

                page.MessageLabel.setText(msg);
            }
            if (installer.isUninstaller())
            {
                    gui.clickButton(buttons.NextButton);
            }
        }
    }
```

But when this command is executed, installer stucks for a long time, till the command is finished. But the execution of command takes a lot of time. When running the same command in test Qt application with the following code:

```
QProcess process;
QString exec = "cmd";
QStringList params;
params << "/C" << "tasklist" << "/M";
int status = 0;
status = process.execute(exec, params);
process.close();
```

It is executed fast.

So there are two questions:

1. Can anyone help me and explain why the execution of `tasklist /M` from installer takes a lot of time, and how can I fix that?
2. May be someone knows the best way of displaying a list of processes that use certain dll?

Comment: There is the [`installer.isProcessRunning`](https://doc.qt.io/qtinstallerframework/scripting-installer.html#isProcessRunning-method) that is part of the framework itself, but I guess that wont help finding the processes using a dll. If you know all processes that could theoretically use it, you could check all of the in loop, but aside from that...

Comment: @Felix , The thing is that I do not know names of processes that use dll. I know only the name of dll that I`m developing, so before installation of new version, I want to check in installer whether any process is using my dll, and propose user to close them.